# AWS S3 file upload giving NetworkingError in iOS with Ionic

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-s3

Getting the following error, when trying to upload a file on S3 via iOS (iPhone device as well as a simulator). All the cocoapods are installed related to AWS.

[Common] _BSMachError: port 12c03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
[discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
There was an error uploading your doc: Network Failure

```
const upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
                    params: {
                        Bucket: sthreepath
                        Key: folderkey,
                        Body: file
                    }
                });
                const promise = upload.promise();
                promise.then(
                    (data) => {
                    },
                    (err) => {
                    }
                );
```

I am uploading a file using the ManagedUpload from AWS.S3

The same code works in Android but in iOS, it is misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

AWS was throwing Networking error due to missing origin in the header.
When uploading image from iOS to S3 bucket the sourceurl was different than normal.

The sourceurl while uploading from iOS is "ionic://localhost:XXXX/vendor.js".

Add the "ionic://localhost:XXXX" to your exception origin in the header and kaboomm!!! It will work.

Cheers!!!